# Losing georeference when creating PDF maps using QGIS on a new Mac

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, mac, avenza

I have been using QGIS and my PC to make georeferenced maps for Avenza.

I have recently switched to a Mac Platform. It all seems to work same except when exported the PDF is not georeferenced.  All seems to be spatially correct when creating maps.

Is this an issue with how Mac downloads our georeferenced USGS imagery we use, which seems to be the only thing that doesn’t seem the same as the PC, or is there something else going on we don’t have setup correctly ?

Comment: Are you using the same QGIS versions on the PC and the Mac?

Comment: I think there is a checkbox somewhere for making exported PDFs georeferenced, is it ticked on?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the 'Save world file' when exporting from the composer window? Would using a .TIFF file work for you instead (if you save as an image and choose .TIFF format)? You can try contacting Avenza Support or QGIS Support.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Mac, I am using QGIS 2.18.16 in Ubuntu 16.04, and I found that it exports georeferenced PDFs from Composer, but only when the reference map is set in export settings.  This is in the Composition tab, Export Settings -

[image: ComposerExportSettings]

I don't have Avenza to test, but resulting PDF shows georeferencing metadata using GDALINFO, and correctly registers in QGIS.

Comment: I installed Avenza for Android and tested a QGIS exported Geo PDF.  It seems to work fine.